# How to switch frontface camera to backface camera via videojs-record for image capturing?

Tags: javascript, record, video.js, video-camera, videojs-record

This works for video (With the code snippet camera changes to backface camera)

```
 videoPlayer.record().stopDevice();
 videoPlayer.record().setVideoInput('backface-camera-device-id');
```

But analogically for image doesn't change anything.
Camera still the same (Only frontface camera)

```
 imagePlayer.record().stopDevice();
 imagePlayer.record().setVideoInput('backface-camera-device-id');
```

My options for imagePlayer is

```
const options = {
                controls: true,
                width: width,
                height: height,
                controlBar: {
                    volumePanel: true
                },
                plugins: {
                    record: {
                        image: true,
                        imageOutputType: 'blob',
                        mandatory: {
                            minWidth: 1280,
                            minHeight: 720,
                        },
                        frameWidth: 1280,
                        frameHeight: 720,
                    }
                }
            };
const imagePlayer = videojs('image-frame', options);
```

Image frame is

```
<video id="image-frame"></video>
```

My video options (works only with video)

```
const options = {
                controls: true,
                width: width,
                height: height,
                fluid: false,
                controlBar: {
                    volumePanel: false,
                    cameraButton: true,
                },
                plugins: {
                    record: {
                        audio: true,
                        video: true,
                        videoEngine: 'recordrtc',
                        maxLength: 120,
                        debug: true,
                        mandatory: {
                            minWidth: 1280,
                            minHeight: 720,
                        },
                        frameWidth: 1280,
                        frameHeight: 720,
                        timeSlice: 1000
                    }
                }
            };
```

Glad to any help or clue to solve the camera switching problem!

Comment: What approaches did you try so far? Have you tried passing `video: { deviceId: {exact: deviceId} }` to the initializer instead of setting it afterwards?

Comment: @milgner, I have tried both, 
`video: { deviceId: {exact: deviceId} }` and `image: { deviceId: {exact: deviceId} }` - still working only for video, but with image - doesn't work.

Comment: @Andrii any updates on this issue. i'm having same problem

Answer (score 1):

```
imagePlayer.record().recordImage = {deviceId: {exact: 'backface-camera-device-id'}};
imagePlayer.record().stopDevice();
imagePlayer.record().getDevice();
```

worked for me.